# Casting void* to several types known only at runtime

Tags: c++, malloc, void-pointers, generic-programming

I am connecting my C++ program to a C++ framework.

The framework returns a void* pointer, which points to a set of data initialised using malloc():

```
void* getData() {
    return framework->returnPointer();
}
```

The type of the data is known only at runtime (from my program), the framework has the following function:

```
size_t ndf_sizeof(ndf_typeid id) {
    switch(id) {
        case NDF_INT64:
            return sizeof(int64_t);
        case NDF_FLOAT:
            return sizeof(float);
        case NDF_DOUBLE:
            return sizeof(double);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The data can take several different types, and the type is stored as an ndf_type (i.e. an integer identifier for data types). The data will not change type during runtime. I can retrieve the ndf_type of the data, and can also  retrieve the size of the data.

I need to be able to do two things:

1. Declare and initialize a buffer of the same type as the data at runtime
2. Iterate through the data and place values into my buffer

My difficulty occurs when working around the void* pointer, and knowing the data type only at run-time, which can itself take several different types. I have attempted to use templates and generic data structures, but to no avail.

Solutions to this problem are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Since declarations happen during compile time, you can't declare a type during runtime.

You can, however, declare all possible types during compile time, prepare pointers of these types and, during runtime, cast to an appropriate pointer. Upon your request, I elaborate that.

I assume you have a pointer, say: void * raw_data, and you know the type, ndf_typeid id.

You can assign the pointer you need like that:

```
int64_t *p1 = 0;
float   *p2 = 0;
double  *p3 = 0;
switch(id) {
    case NDF_INT64:   p0 = (int64_t  *) raw_data; break;
    case NDF_FLOAT:   p1 = (float    *) raw_data; break;
    case NDF_DOUBLE:  p2 = (double   *) raw_data; break;
}
```

However, the real work begins after that - you want to do something, and you will have lots of "if" and "case" statements in order to execute the code you want to execute. That's why sometimes people use virtual methods:

```
struct Any {
   size_t _size;
   virtual void doit() = 0;
};

template < typename T > struct Typ: Any {
   T _data;
   Typ ( void * data ): _size(sizeof(T)), _data(*(T*)data) {}
   virtual void doit {
      cout << _data << " has size " << _size;
   }
}

Any * any = 0;

switch(id) {
   case NDF_INT64:   any = new Typ<int64_t> (raw_data); break;
   case NDF_FLOAT:   any = new Typ<float  > (raw_data); break;
   case NDF_DOUBLE:  any = new Typ<double > (raw_data); break;
}

any->doit();
```

This will just print out the value. You can override doit for each Typ then:

```
template<> void Typ<float>::doit() {
   cout << "this is a float: " << _data;
}
```

And that allows you to do different work depending on the type.

Comment: Could you explain this further?

Answer (score 0):

*Declare and initialize a buffer of the same type as the data at runtime*

No, you can't do this as you don't know what type is data actually. Closest you can do is declare buffer for supporting every type and then at run time you decide which buffer needs to be filled.